# Using log4j2 Configuration name in the RollingFileAppender's fileName

Tags: java, log4j2

In the log4j2 examples, some configurations have names:

```
<Configuration status="debug" strict="true" name="MyApplication1"
           packages="org.apache.logging.log4j.test">
```

I would like to use this name in the filename pattern for RollingFileAppender:

```
<RollingFile name="File" fileName="/user/home/abc/${ctx:name}.log">...</RollingFile>
```

Unfortunately, "${ctx:name}" doesn't make sense to log4j, neither do "${name}" nor "${log4j:name}", so I was wondering if I could get the Configuration name at all for this purpose...

Answer (score 0):

you can add it to `Properties` section

```
<Configuration status="debug" name="app-config" packages="org.apache.logging.log4j.test">
<Properties>
   <Property name="filename">app-file</Property>
</Properties>
```

and use it later on

```
<RollingFile name="File" fileName="/user/home/abc/${filename}.log">
```

Comment: That is exactly what I've done, but I really wanted to use the name of the configuration, because it is exactly the same as the name of the file in my case and I want to avoid duplication.